# Multiple independent charts / widgets on MVC 4 view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, iframe, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a dashboard application that has multiple independent widgets based on the common query string parameters passed. In MVC, each widget has separate controller --> view --> JS file (that makes AJAX calls to get JSON from WCF). Now, I need to create a master page that will "host" all of these independent widgets. How can I make sure that these widgets are truely "independent"? IE has concurrent connection cap that could be made to a single server. Will iframe serve the purpose? Should I host each widget in a separate iframe on this master page? What are more suitable and acceptible alternatives? Use partial views?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: The question is too old that I had to recall my memory for the project that I was working on. Yes, finally we went for the partial views, where each widget was hosted by a partial view containing its own client side code and controller actions to serve the data. Hope this helps.